# 405 Method Not Allowed 405 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Cache-Control:[no-cache] Content-Type:[application/xml;charset=utf-8]

Tags: go

I have created an Odata service in HANA server and trying to PUT a new record using go language.

But getting "405 Method Not Allowed 405 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Cache-Control:[no-cache] Content-Type:[application/xml;charset=utf-8]" error status on process.

**Below is the code sample:**

```
client := &http.Client{}
http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
newEmployee := result{
    ID:     5,
    Name:   "Mr Z",
    FNAME:  "Mr.",
    LNAME:  "Z",
    EXTEN:  "91",
    MOBILE: "1234567809",
}
json, err := json.Marshal(newEmployee)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(newEmployee)
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPut, lUrl, bytes.NewBuffer(json))
    req.SetBasicAuth(username, passwd)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(resp)
        }
    }
}
```

Program is executing perfectly for Deleting or Fetching records.

I have created a SAPUI5 application with all Insert, Delete and Fetch records functionality with same odata Service and it's working correctly.

Comment: `405 Method Not Allowed` means the resource you are trying to access does not support `PUT` requests. Since we don't know the URL, we can't help you further.

Comment: Hi Marc, The PUT method is working correctly in SAPUI5 application. I can share oData link but without credential it won't work.

Comment: I would say double check the URL, parameters, and authentication settings. It's also possible the server is returning 405 rather than the more appropriate error.